# MySQL, structure of database of home sensors

Tags: mysql

I do have some sensors in my house. And right now I going to log them into a database. So as I am new to MySQL I will need some help by setting up the right structure.
Actual values are getting stored automatic every 5 minutes.
As the amount of values is after running a year really high I will write a C# program what will calculate a MIN, MAX & AVG for each day and save the values for this day.

This the structure I want to have and as I know sub tables are not allowed in MySQL I will need help:

```
Database: SensorData
              |
              |-----------------------
              |                      |
Tables:   LivingRoom              Outside
              |                      |
              |------------          |
              |           |          |
Columns: Temperature  Humidity    Temperature
```

These columns are holding the "actual" day values.
But now I will calculate the MIN, MAX and AVG of these columns.
And I don't know where to place the results that I can easy choose like:
Sensordata.LivingRoom.Temperature.MIN or Sensordata.LivingRoom.Temperature.MAX.

But this will need a table in a column...

The tables are very easy and look like this:

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Datum          | timestamp    | NO   | PRI | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
| Temperatur     | decimal(5,2) | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

or

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Datum          | timestamp    | NO   | PRI | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
| Temperatur     | decimal(5,2) | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| Humidity       | decimal(5,2) | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

May somebody have an idea for an intelligent solution...
I am complete flexible about the database/table/column design as I just started designing.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? In a single table, you can have an ENUM for Living Room/Outside.

```
CREATE TABLE `sensor_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` enum('Living Room','Outside') NOT NULL,
  `time_recorded` datetime NOT NULL,
  `temperature` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `humidity` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and then you can run this query to get MAX, MIN and AVG for all the data you have grouped by day!.

```
SELECT MAX(temperature),MIN(temperature),AVG(temperature) FROM sensor_data GROUP BY DATE(time_recorded) ORDER BY DATE(time_recorded);
```

Comment: ENUM is new to me. thx for that! But this will only combine the two tables to one table. But how to handle the min, max,... for temperature and humidity. If I add a column MIN, MAX and AVG, I have to separate if these are values for temperature or humidity of the sensor.

Comment: You don't really need another table for that. Mysql has built in functions that can do that right on this table when you need it. Example: 

`select MAX(temperature) FROM sensor_data WHERE type = 'Living Room' GROUP BY DATE(time);`

Answer (score 0):

I will delete the actual (all 5 minutes) stored values each day and before I make a backup of this day with min, max,.. I am not interested what temperature was 3 weeks in the past at am 9:20. Anyway, with the enum I think I got a result:

```
CREATE TABLE `sensor_data` (
    `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `sensor` enum('Living Room','Outside') NOT NULL,
    `temperature` decimal(5,2) NULL,
    `humidity` decimal(5,2) NULL,
    `calc_type` enum('none','temperature','humidity') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'none',
    `MIN` decimal(5,2) NULL,
    `MAX` decimal(5,2) NULL,
    `AVG` decimal(5,2) NULL
);
```

Manuel handling:

```
insert into sensor_data (sensor, temperature) values ('Living Room', '24.5');
insert into sensor_data (sensor, humidity) values ('Living Room', '53');
insert into sensor_data (sensor, temperature) values ('Outside', '23.5');

SELECT MIN(temperature) FROM sensor_data WHERE DATE(time) = '2016-06-08' AND sensor = 'Outside';
SELECT MIN(temperature) FROM sensor_data WHERE DATE(time) = '2016-06-08' AND sensor = 'Living Room';
SELECT MIN(humidity) FROM sensor_data WHERE DATE(time) = '2016-06-08' AND sensor = 'Living Room';

INSERT INTO sensor_data (time, sensor, calc_type, MIN) VALUES ('2016-06-08', 'Outside', 'temperature', '23.5');
INSERT INTO sensor_data (time, sensor, calc_type, MIN) VALUES ('2016-06-08', 'Living Room', 'temperature', '24.5');
INSERT INTO sensor_data (time, sensor, calc_type, MIN) VALUES ('2016-06-08', 'Living Room', 'humidity', '53');

SELECT MIN FROM sensor_data WHERE DATE(time) = '2016-06-08' AND sensor = 'Outside' AND calc_type = 'temperature' AND temperature IS NULL;
SELECT MIN FROM sensor_data WHERE DATE(time) = '2016-06-08' AND sensor = 'Living Room' AND calc_type = 'temperature' AND temperature IS NULL;
SELECT MIN FROM sensor_data WHERE DATE(time) = '2016-06-08' AND sensor = 'Living Room' AND calc_type = 'humidity' AND humidity IS NULL;
```

Answer (score -1):

**Table:** sensors

**Description:** Used to store basic sensor information such as name and location

```
CREATE TABLE `sensors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `created` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Table:** sensors_data

**Description:** Used to store sensor data including temperature and humidity based on days and times

```
CREATE TABLE `sensors_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sensor_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `temperature` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `humidity` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Table:** sensors_data

**Description:** Used to store sensor data averages including temperature and humidity based on days

```
CREATE TABLE `sensors_data_average` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sensor_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type_key` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `temperature` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `humidity` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `date` date DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `created` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Table:** types

**Description:** Used to store sensor data types (MIN, MAX, AVG)

```
CREATE TABLE `type` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

INSERT INTO type SET `name` = 'Minimum', `key` = 'min', created = NOW(), modified = NOW();
INSERT INTO type SET `name` = 'Maximum', `key` = 'max', created = NOW(), modified = NOW();
INSERT INTO type SET `name` = 'Average', `key` = 'avg', created = NOW(), modified = NOW();
```

Based on these tables, here are your relationships:

```
sensors have many sensors_data

sensors have many sensors_data_average

sensors_data belongs to sensors

sensors_data_average belongs to sensors

sensors_data_average has one type
```

You create and populate the sensors_data_average table using the values in the sensors_data every day, week or month and then remove the data that was used to create the averages from the database.